# How to define array in Macros in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macros, xcode4.2, nsarray

Is there any possibility to define arrays in macro in objective-c.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7100455/730701).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also just do:

```
#define MY_ARRAY @[ @"foo", @"bar" ]
```

Comment: can u tell me how to declare array of long value in #define?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you can define arrays in macros. e.g

```
#define MY_ARRAY [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:someObj1, someObj2, nil]
```

Comment: @Ehsan Can you pls tell how to access or retrieve this.

Comment: It would be the same as you would use an NSMutableArray object, e.g

`NSLog(@"Object at index 0 is %@",[MY_ARRAY objectAtIndex:0]);`

Comment: how to add aobject ?like :[ MY_ARRAY addobject:@"obj"];